# how to show lines separately without overlapping when values are same

Tags: google-visualization, linechart

Working on google charts API (Line chart).I have same set of values which are used to draw lines for server and shipping, as the values are same two lines are overlapping as shown in the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/PNA1XQapRzvxGfm7behd?p=preview

Is there a way where we can see two lines instead of overlapping when they have the same values?

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var chart1 = {};
    chart1.type = "LineChart";
    chart1.displayed = false;
    chart1.data = {
      "cols": [{
        id: "month",
        label: "Month",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        id: "laptop-id",
        label: "Laptop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "desktop-id",
        label: "Desktop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "server-id",
        label: "Server",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "cost-id",
        label: "Shipping",
        type: "number"
      }],
      "rows": [{
        c: [{
          v: "January"
        }, {
          v: 19,
         }, {
          v: 12,
         }, {
          v: 7, //server
         }, {
          v: 7  //shipping
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
          v: "February"
        }, {
          v: 13
        }, {
          v: 1,
         }, {
          v: 12  //server
        }, {
          v: 12  //shipping
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "March"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }, {
            v: 5
          }, { 
            v: 11  //server
          }, {
            v: 11  //shipping
          }
        ]
      }]
    };
    chart1.options = {
      "title": "Sales per month",
      "colors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "defaultColors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "isStacked": "percent",
       focusTarget: 'category',
      "fill": 20,
      "displayExactValues": true,
      "vAxis": {
        "title": "Sales unit",
        "gridlines": {
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      "hAxis": {
        "title": "Date"
      }
    };
    chart1.view = {
      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    };
    $scope.myChart = chart1;
  });
```

Comment: the only way would be to show one of the lines on a different axis -- another option might be to set a `pointSize` on one of the series...

Comment: I like the option of using pointSize on one of the series.Can you please/redirect to an example using pointSize on one of the series. I tried to find out one but could not find..thanks.@WhiteHat

Answer (score 0):

use the `series` chart option to set `pointSize` on a specific series

the following will change the *server* series in the example provided...

```
  series: {
    2: {
      pointSize: 8
    }
  }
```

see [forked plnker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ixGjtCfGjnJtC3vwOxJu?p=preview)...